# Python Django Errno 54 'Connection reset by peer'

Tags: python, django, sockets

Having some trouble debugging this. I get this error always when i first start my app up, then intermittently thereafter. Could someone please help me by throwing out some debugging techniques? I've tried using a proxy inspector - to no avail, i didn't see anything useful. I've tried the suggestions about setting my SITE_URL in my django settings. I've tried with and without http:// with and without the port... Here's the unhelpful error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 57917)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/Users/ryan/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-2PUjdB8V/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 171, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/Users/ryan/.local/share/virtualenvs/portal-2PUjdB8V/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 179, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

The app seems to function properly even with this connection reset but it's been driving me crazy trying to debug.

Comment: I got an error when I ran it from the editor, not the terminal.) / run from terminal : python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 30, accepted):

FFS... so dumb. I noticed that it was always resetting after not finding a favicon so I added one... Even though I never explicitly loaded one, django appears to try and load a default one from the root of the project... This doesn't happen for any of the other devs working on the project either. weird.
(For completeness) If anyone else stumbles upon this i used [favicon io](https://favicon.io/favicon-generator/) to make a simple text one. Then i loaded it into my html like so:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}" />
...
```

Be sure to set your static path correctly in settings.

Comment: Does it mean each webpage need to include this? if so, really ridiculous.  AND I would seek a method to disable this active seeking of favicon.ico.

Comment: Even if the file name is case insensitive or file missed. We will get this error. I am using python 3.6 and django 2.2.

Answer (score 12):

The same behaviour is seen if the favicon is in .png format as opposed to .ico.

Also, contrary to advice seen on other sites, downgrading Python to v3.6 does not solve the problem. [screenshot of error w. png favicon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHwrV.jpg)

Seems to be a Django issue, It will probably be fixed permanently in a future Django release.

Following https://bugs.python.org/issue27682#msg348302 I made the changes shown:
[image: code changes]

I then replaced BrokenPipeError with ConnectionAbortedError. This seems to handle the exception.

Update for Django 3: I have the following changes in basehttp.py (rev.1.2.1) to get rid of all the pesky broken pipe error messages:

```
Line 55: - return issubclass(exc_type, BrokenPipeError)
Line 55: + return issubclass(exc_type, (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionAbortedError, ConnectionResetError))

Line 71: - logger.info("- Broken pipe from %s\n", client_address)
Line 71: + pass
```

Comment: I found it necessary to modify the return as such to eliminate this error on Mac: `return issubclass(exc_type, (BrokenPipeError, ConnectionResetError))`

Comment: Even if the file name is case insensitive or file missed. We will get this error. I am using python 3.6 and django 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue `ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer`.

In my case the issue was trying to serve static files through development server with `debug settings to False`, development server can serve static files only when `debug` is set to `True` in settings file.

In my settings file i replace

```
DEBUG = False
```

with

```
DEBUG = True
```

After that, I restart my development server and it works for me!

Answer (score 1):

None of the current answers worked for me. This is how I made the error go away during development on MacOS for Django 3 (untested on other versions).

Create a custom runserver management command in one of your project apps which is only different when `DEBUG==True` and you are on a Mac. Pay particular attention to `Command.get_handler`:

```py
#myapp/management/commands/runserver.py


import platform

import django.core.servers.basehttp
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver import Command as RunserverCommand
from django.core.servers.basehttp import ServerHandler


def handle_one_request(self):
    """
    Exact copy of django.core.servers.WSGIRequestHandler.handle_one_request except it
    Completely ignores "ConnectionResetError: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer"
    Which seems to be only noise on MacOS.
    """
    try:
        self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
    except ConnectionResetError:
        return
    if len(self.raw_requestline) > 65536:
        self.requestline = ""
        self.request_version = ""
        self.command = ""
        self.send_error(414)
        return

    if not self.parse_request():  # An error code has been sent, just exit
        return

    handler = ServerHandler(self.rfile, self.wfile, self.get_stderr(), self.get_environ())
    handler.request_handler = self  # backpointer for logging & connection closing
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())


class Command(RunserverCommand):
    def get_handler(self, *args, **options):
        if settings.DEBUG and platform.platform().upper().startswith("DARWIN"):
            # patch the offending code
            django.core.servers.basehttp.WSGIRequestHandler.handle_one_request.__code__ = handle_one_request.__code__

        return super().get_handler(*args, **options)
```

And add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` above the `django.contrib.staticfiles`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  . . .
  "myapp",
  "django.contrib.staticfiles",
  . . .
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue when i switch from development to production.

After i do collectstatic it worked normal again, my guess is it's missing static dir path for production

do this before you switch to production environment

> python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my project. Maybe this post can help someone.
In my case the problem was I call the function from the button with `onclick` like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning"  onclick="submitData();">Caption</a>
```

I changed this to a better way:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="button-action">Caption</button>
```

And then handle the click:

```
document.getElementById('button-action').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    submitData()
})
```